# Compilation errors with MikTex 22.3 + xetex

Tags: xetex, miktex

I am a long-time user of MikTeX, with much happiness. But not today. It seems there is something messed up in MikTeX 22.3.  I have tried updates, downgrades, reinstalls, nothing is working. I tried to compile this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
Hi
\end{document}
```

with

```
xelatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode paper.tex
```

and I get errors like this on two machines I have tried:

```
! Paragraph ended before \__sys_tmp:w was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
```

with the full log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.4.5)  5 APR 2022 11:48
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./paper.tex
(paper.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex
.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: XeTeX
 ()
! Argument of \__sys_tmp:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
\q_stop \__int_eval_end: 
! Paragraph ended before \__sys_tmp:w was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_par:D 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_par:D 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! You can't use `\numexpr' in horizontal mode.
\int_compare:nNnTF ...nt_eval:w #1#2\__int_eval:w 
                                                  #3\__int_eval_end: \__prg_...
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

Missing character: There is no ^^@ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text
;!
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count189
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count190
\g__graphics_track_int=\count191
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count192
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count193
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count194
) (paper.aux)
\openout1 = `paper.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 2
.

(C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
 [1

]
(paper.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 449 strings out of 410967
 8886 string characters out of 2824160
 303500 words of memory out of 3000000
 21258 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469267 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 33i,5n,38p,146b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on paper.pdf (1 page).
```

Edit:

Here is the output in Powershell (note how somehow the executable cannot be found and yet also called):

```
(base) PS C:\> where extractbb
(base) PS C:\> extractbb --version

This is extractbb Version 20211117

Copyright (C) 2008-2021 by Jin-Hwan Cho and Matthias Franz
```

Edit 2:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\ihb\Desktop> get-command extractbb

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     extractbb.exe                                      22.3.0.0   C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\extractbb.exe


(base) PS C:\Users\ihb\Desktop> get-command xelatex

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     xelatex.exe                                        22.3.0.0   C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe


(base) PS C:\Users\ihb\Desktop> xelatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode MWE.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=xelatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex
.def ()
! Argument of \__sys_tmp:w has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }

Runaway argument?
\q_stop \__int_eval_end:
! Paragraph ended before \__sys_tmp:w was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \scan_stop:
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   \tex_par:D
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \tex_par:D
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }

! You can't use `\numexpr' in horizontal mode.
\int_compare:nNnTF ...nt_eval:w #1#2\__int_eval:w
                                                  #3\__int_eval_end: \__prg_...
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }

Missing character: There is no ^^@ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text
;!
) (MWE.aux)
(C:\Users\ihb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd) [1]
(MWE.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on MWE.log.
```

Comment: I think you haven't extractbb installed or can't call it.

Comment: what do you get if you run on the terminal `where extractbb`?

Comment: Hm, in mine recent MiKTeX installation (MiKTeX 22.3) it works fine. No errors, no warnings, no bad boxes.

Comment: ``where extractbb`` gives nothing, but it is definitely in the bin folder. Odd.

Comment: but I can do ``extractbb --version``, and it resolves and prints the version info

Comment: Which terminal are you using?  The normal cmd?

Comment: I showed my example above.  For some reason CMD isn't working today.

Comment: `where` doesn't work in the powershell, use `get-command extractbb` there. Did you call xelatex from the same powershell session? Exactly as you showed it above?

Comment: I added edit 2 with what you asked for.

Comment: This is the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335300/cmd-crashes-with-exit-code-1-after-uninstalling-anaconda